# How to import bower_components with app built by brunch?

Tags: jquery, brunch

I'm still getting my bearings with brunch. I have a fundamental class and jasmine spec being built and tested successfully.

Now it's time to start importing other dependencies for use, the first of which will be jQuery and make `$` available.  The libraries are already configured and downloaded in the `bower_components` directory.

While my config has evolved a bit, it might be useful to point to the skeleton I started with: [brunch-with-hipsters](https://github.com/elving/brunch-with-hipsters).

How do you import and make jQuery available as `$` to my coffeescript class from `bower_components`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was a bit of a red herring.

`coffeelint` was enabled and giving me warnings when running brunch, but since I'm beginning, I wasn't worried about it.  Nonetheless, there were enough warnings that it scrolled off the screen.

I noticed that I had configured:

```
        'js/vendor.js': /^(bower_components|vendor)/
        'js/app.js': /^app/
```

yet no vendor.js appeared.  Scrolling up, I found this error:

```
error: [Error: Component JSON file ".../bower_components/jquery-simulate/.bower.json" 
must have `main` property. See https://github.com/paulmillr/read-components#README]
```

Quite simply, I needed to provide an `overrides` section because `jquery-simulate` doesn't provide a .bower.json file (I'm accessing it directly from git).

In the end, fixing this meant vendor.js was generated and $ was available.

Comment: You can see how to use the overrides feature here: https://github.com/paulmillr/read-components

Answer (score 0):

From your app root `npm install -g bower`, then update `brunch-config.[js|coffee]` so Bower components are piped into `vendor.js` or `app.js` using [`joinTo`](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#files) as described in the [Brunch config doc](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md).

Once the configuration is saved, executing `brunch watch` will start the watcher and monitor application changes. Any changes to `bower.json` or the app thereafter will automatically fetch Bower deps (if necessary), recompile the application and live-reload any connected user agents.

**Note:** If a Bower component does not have a `main` section, specify an `overrides` section so you can define the `main`s yourself as described in [read-components](https://github.com/paulmillr/read-components). Otherwise you'll get an error when trying to build the app.